# In SwiftUI / Combine, how can two ObservableObjects coordinate?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

My app has two `ObservableObject`s:

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    @StateObject private var foo = Foo()
    @StateObject private var bar = Bar()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppView()
                .environmentObject(foo)
                .environmentObject(bar)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Foo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var operationResult: Bool?

    private let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

    func start() {
        operationQueue.addOperation(SomeOperation())
        // SomeOperation will set operationResult
    }
}
```

```
class Bar: ObservableObject {
    @Published var resultsAvailable = false

    func updateResults(operationResult: Bool) {
        if operationResult && someOtherCondition {
            resultsAvailable = true
        }
    }
}
```

At some point, `Foo` is doing some work on a background thread. When it completes, state in `Bar` needs to be updated, perhaps by calling `updateResults()`. In a traditional UIKit app, I might coordinate this by setting a callback handler or posting an `NSNotification`.

Instead of passing `operationResult` around via a notification or handler, is there a way for `Bar` to subscribe to changes to `Foo`'s `operationResult` property? In examples I've found so far, it seems like the subscriptions may only be available inside `View` structs, but I haven't been able to confirm or deny that.

Comment: Can you explain the context for why you need to coordinate these two objects? My thinking is a DispatchGroup. Use it to hold the values until the group is triggered, then update both values from the group. But that would still have each of them updating separately of one another. Context might be a little more important in this example.

Comment: `Foo` is a fairly large class responsible for crunching a lot of data in the background (takes several seconds to finish even on a newer device). `Bar` needs to understand the result of the data crunching, in combination with some user preferences, to set state appropriate to the user's intent. So `Foo` doesn't need to know about `Bar` and they're mostly separate concerns, but `Bar` does need the output of `Foo`. `Foo` might rerun at any time as new data becomes available so they need to coordinate.

Comment: You can subscribe to a @Published property so that is one way to go, if you don't want that coupling between Foo and Bar then maybe notifications is a good solution here (NotificationCenter has a publisher so you can subscribe to notifications if you want to keep this in the Combine realm so to speak)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson *"You can subscribe to a `@Published` property"* Can you show how? That's basically my question.

Comment: `foo.$operationResult.sink(receiveValue: { result in ... }.store(in: &...)`

Comment: So `Bar` needs a reference to `Foo`? There's no equivalent of `@EnvironmentObject` I can use?

Comment: You store the subscription using `.store(in:)` so you don't to store Foo as a property but Bar needs access to the Foo object it wants to subscribe to. If you are not going to have more than one instance of Foo you could implement it with a `shared` property (or a singleton). `Foo.shared.$operationResult.sink(...`

Comment: you can try `onChange` in the `View`. When the `@Published` in Foo changes do something in Bar. But Notifications or making a custom `Delegate` are probably cleaner options.

Comment: Using Joakim's suggestion above, I would "wire them up" during .onAppear in the view. So, it'll get wired up once - when the view is about to be displayed.

Comment: I went with `Foo.shared.$operationResult.sink(…)` since the whole point of my question was to avoid doing anything in the view